# how to inherit only one block in jinja2?

Tags: python, inheritance, jinja2

I have a file *base.json* where:

```
{
    param1: value1,
{%- block block1 %}
    param2: {
        param3: value3,
        param4: value4
    }
{%- endblock %}
}
```

and a file *result.json*:

```
{% extends "base.json" %}
someinfo
{% block block1 %}{% endblock %}
```

But after rendering *result.json*, I get the whole information from *base.json* without `someinfo@` from *result.json* template.

What is the correct way to inherit only one block from the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending your template is not what you are looking to do, extends allows the reuse of a full template, with the rewrite of specific blocks:

Given: *base.json*

```
{
    param1: value1,
{%- block block1 %}
    param2: {
        param3: value3,
        param4: value4
    }
{%- endblock %}
}
```

And *result.json*

```
{% extends "base.json" %}
{%- block block1 %}
    param5: {
        param6: value6,
        param7: value7
    }
{%- endblock %}
```

Those will render as:

```
{
    param1: value1,
    param5: {
        param6: value6,
        param7: value7
    }
}
```

---

In your case what you can do is to use an [`include`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#include).

With *partial.json*

```
    param5: {
        param6: value6,
        param7: value7
    }
```

And *result.json*

```
{
    param8: value8,
{% include "partial.json" %}
}
```

Those will render as:

```
{
    param8: value8,
    param5: {
        param6: value6,
        param7: value7
    }
}
```

And because the file is a partial, that you just inculde some place else, you can also include it in a block, if you want to rewrite it somewhere:

*base.json*

```
{
    param1: value1,
{%- block block1 %}
{% include "partial.json" %}
{%- endblock %}
}
```

Comment: thank you! ^_^ 
also find {%- filter indent(width=4) %}
with {% include %} - what i need :)